# Debezium Mysql connector with Kafka not reading Db changes after some period of time why?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, debezium

We are using debezium mysql connector with kafka.

Initially when I start Kafka connector with Debezium and do any DML changes (like insert or update) in db debezium is able to read db binary logs and post the changes to KAFKA topics.

After some period of time it was not picking the db changes why?

Is there anything like after some time connector will get into inactive mode or what.

Again if I delete all log files and restart kafka connector that time it was able to pick db changes and working properly.

Comment: Can you share kafka connect logs?

Comment: Can you also check the Kafka Connect status endpoint for the connector to see if it is actually still running or did it encounter any failure?